# edit module requirements when compiling kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, raspberry-pi, kernel-parameters

I would like to compile the realtime kernel for raspberry pi (https://github.com/emlid/linux-rt-rpi) and want to use the pi with a soundcard - the tascam us122l.

The problem that I have is the compilation of the us122l module requires X86 to be selected, although I suspect that this is a kernel fudge, in that I know the code of the driver and it is no different from any of the other soundcard drivers from snd_usb*.  I am going to ask the alsa dev team but I want to compile the kernel now.

Is there any way to edit the kernel source scripts to change the requirements for this module?

│ Symbol: SND_USB_US122L [=n]

|Type  : tristate                                                                                                                                                     │
  │ Prompt: Tascam US-122L USB driver                                                                                                                                    │
  │   Location:                                                                                                                                                          │
  │     -> Device Drivers                                                                                                                                                │
  │       -> Sound card support (SOUND [=y])                                                                                                                             │
  │         -> Advanced Linux Sound Architecture (SND [=m])                                                                                                              │
  │ (1)       -> USB sound devices (SND_USB [=y])                                                                                                                        │
  │   Defined at sound/usb/Kconfig:92                                                                                                                                    │
  │   Depends on: SOUND [=y] && !M68K && !UML && SND [=m] && SND_USB [=y] && USB [=y] && X86   *---*     *Here is the problem*
                                                                        │
  │   Selects: SND_HWDEP [=m] && SND_RAWMIDI [=m]

Answer (score 1):

Hi please follow following steps to compile driver as module for arm architecture.

1. Cross-compiling the rt kernel on Linux

   Export the following variables to specify cross-compilation options:

   ```
   export ARCH=arm

   export CROSS_COMPILE=~/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf- raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-

   make bcmrpi_rt_defconfig
   ```
2. Compile the kernel:

   ```
   make -j5
   ```
3. Edit Makefile present at sound/usb folder.

e.g

```
snd-usb-audio-objs :=   card.o \
                        clock.o \
                        endpoint.o \
                        format.o \
                        helper.o \
                        mixer.o \
                        mixer_quirks.o \
                        pcm.o \
                        proc.o \
                        quirks.o \
                        stream.o

snd-usbmidi-lib-objs := midi.o

# Toplevel Module Dependency
obj-m += snd-usb-audio.o snd-usbmidi-lib.o

obj-m += snd-usbmidi-lib.o
obj-m += snd-usbmidi-lib.o
obj-m += snd-usbmidi-lib.o

obj-m += misc/ usx2y/ caiaq/ 6fire/ hiface/ bcd2000/
```

4. Compile driver as module

   ```
    make modules M=sound/usb
   ```